# How long is side $a$ in this right triangle if $a = b$, given $c$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, triangles

A right angled triangle has side lengths labeled as so.

[A common geometric construction that shows three squares sitting upon the sides of a right triangle with lengths A, B, and C](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/d/d2/Pythagorean.svg)

However unlike in this diagram $a = b$.

How can $a$ be calculated given $c$?

Would $a = c \cdot d$ where $d$ is a constant?

Comment: A suggestion:  the use of $N$ as a variable is prone to make people think it is a natural number, so it should be avoided.  $D$ would be a better choice.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We know that $c^2 = a^2+b^2$ from Pythagorean Theorem or $c^2 = 2a^2$. Thus $c = a \sqrt{2}$.

Comment: ... and so $a = \frac{c}{\sqrt{2}}$, making $N = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \approx 0.7071$

Answer (score 2):

If A=B , then the angles of the triangle are 45:45:90,
And as per the 45:45:90 theorem, the side opposite the 45 degree angle is `hypotenuse/√2`

So in this case value of `A` will be `C/√2`